# How to pass values from javascript to HTML and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do as follow:

1. Get a list of paired values - each value includes a name and a number
2. present the user with a list of buttons , each button shows the name from the name-value pair, so if I get 10 pairs, I will present 10 buttons
3. when the user clicks the chosen name, the button invokes a JS with the name-value matched.

I am very new to HTML , so this part is the problematic for me.
The page is not required to look nice at this stage, just function correctly.

```
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>
    <script>
    var pairs = [
        {
            "name_1": 123
        },
        {
            "name_2": 983
        },
        {
            "name_3": 567
        }
    ];

    function present_buttons(pairs) {
        for (var i in pairs) {
            console.log(`index  = ${i}`);
            console.log(`name  = ${pair[i].name}`);
            console.log(`value  = ${pair[i].value}`);
            // send info the the HTML section, so present proper names on buttons
            // make sure to hook matching value for each button so it will be sent correctly to the use_value function later on
        }
    }

    function use_value(value) {
        // do something with the value triggered by the matching name button
    }
    </script>
    <!--
get names to present on buttons from the present_buttons()
when a button is clicked , send the matching value to the use_value() function

-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in helping  Rob , @Matansh answer cleared the fog for me on how to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var pairs = [
                { "name_1" : 123 } , 
                { "name_2" : 983 } , 
                { "name_3" : 567 } 
            ];

            for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
                var button = document.createElement('button');
                var pair = pairs[i];

                button.innerHTML = Object.keys(pair)[0];
                button.addEventListener('click', function (pair) {
                    use_value(pair);
                }.bind(this, pair));

                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(button);
            }


            function use_value(value)  {

                // do something with the value triggered by the matching name button
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Happy to help :)